# How to use the attribute "title" without relying on "pattern"?

Tags: php, html, input, attributes, title

So I'm a beginner in HTML/PHP programming. I need to create a basic form (username/password/email) that catches errors, and I discovered the HTML attribute "title" that does a very good job displaying them, when the pattern is not met.

However, I don't think I can create a pattern that catches errors when confirming the password (the idea is to force the user to type the same password two times).

My goal here is to display something like this when catching an error even thought no pattern has been infringed [image]

That's my code in case you need it:

```html
<input type="password" name="pw" size="16" value="<?=$infosVal[3]?>" placeholder="Password" minlength="6">
<input type="password" name="repeat" size="16" value="<?=$infosVal[4]?>" placeholder="Repeat" minlength="6">
```

Is there any way I can do that ? Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a HTML-only solution for checking if two fields are the same. You could do the confirmation check using javascript (client side) or PHP (serverside)

Comment: That's not my question. I know I will need PHP to catch errors, my goal here is to display the error in a good-looking way, so using the attribute title. If i don't use the attribute title I can display a bad-looking message like [this](https://i.imgur.com/z3PWzAI.png) but the result would be weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form method='post'>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name='pass1' oninput="document.querySelector('#pass2').pattern=this.value" required=""> <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id='pass2' name='pass2'
     pattern="" title="The second password does not match the first!" required="" /><br>
     <input type="submit" name="check">
</form>
```

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["check"])){
        $password = $_POST["pass1"];
        $confirmedPassword = $_POST["pass2"];
        if($password === $confirmedPassword)
            print('login success!');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to do this HTML/PHP only.

Comment: I update the answer to fit what you need doing it with HTML/PHP only.check it out.

Comment: while this may seem obvious, it works terribly on special characters. i used preg_quote() to make it work

Comment: i don't make an attempt with special characters, if you can share with us how you make it works with `preg_quote()`?